# How to use a SMB URL with user/userid that contains an @ symbol?

Tags: samba, smb

I want to use a Samba share from the command line but I have an user (userid) with an <kbd>@</kbd> symbol.

It works fine from a GUI login dialog, but I have not been able to use any of the command line Samba utilities.

Is there a way to escape it? The accounts are managed by LDAP I believe and the server is a NAS (Linux based, I assume).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That [doesn't seem to be possible](https://git.samba.org/?p=samba.git;a=blob;f=source3/libsmb/cliconnect.c;h=8653ba7d0857769425d0da8437352f44dbfbb852;hb=f7c3d2984be6aaae711ff144e929b5e5dc98a03e#l1957) using `smbclient` (from Samba 3.x), but it should work using `smbclient4` (from Samba 4.x).